# GeoCoder gives default value for invalid zip codes

Tags: zip, geocoding, google-geocoder

I am using Geocoder to get a location based on the ZIP code (I am restricting it to just the US). Everything works fine except that if I input an invalid zip (90123, for example), it gives me a default value instead of giving `ZERO_RESULTS`. The default value happens to be Denton, Texas (for all invalid codes). How can I prevent this from happening, or tell whether a code is invalid to avoid this issue?

I am using this code:

```
geocoder.geocode({ 'address': zip,  componentRestrictions: {country: 'us'} }, function (results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
                        jQuery('#zipErrorId').html("INVALID");
                    }
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        geocoder.geocode({'latLng': results[0].geometry.location}, function(results, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                            if (results[1]) {
                                var cityState = getCityState(results);
                                // like Apple Valley, Minnesota
                                var cityStateArr = cityState.split('|');
                                   ---------------------------
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is returning Prudential Tower in Boston, MA. Don't know why.

It sends back the value you entered. So in results.address_components.short_name, will be the value it returned. So for example if I search on "00000,United States", the results.address_components.short_name will be "02199" (the zip of the aforementioned building). If that doesn't match the value you gave it, it was probably an invalid zip.